# How can this function be tested with vows?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, vows

How can the following function, intended to add routes to express.js app based on an object hierarchy, be tested using vows.js cleanly without breaking vows' separation of the topic and the vow?

```
var addRoutes = function(routeObject, app, path) {

    var httpVerbs = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'];

    path = path || '';

    for(var property in routeObject){
        var routesAdded = false;
        for (var verbIndex in httpVerbs) {
            var verb = httpVerbs[verbIndex];
            var completePath, handler;
            if (property === verb) {
                if (typeof(routeObject[verb]) === 'function') {
                    handler = routeObject[verb];
                    completePath = path;
                } else {
                    handler = routeObject[verb].handler;
                    completePath = path + (routeObject[verb].params || '');
                }
                app[verb](completePath, handler);
                routesAdded = true;
            }
        }
        if (!routesAdded) {
            addRoutes(routeObject[property], app, path + '/' + property);
        }
    }
};
```

The test should confirm that functions corresponding to http verbs are called on the app object. e.g. if routeObject is:

```
{
    tracker: {
        message: {
            get: {
                handler: function (req, res) {
                    res.send("respond with a resource");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then

```
app.get('/tracker/message', function (req, res) {
                            res.send("respond with a resource");
                        });
```

should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    request = require('request');

var verbs = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
    app = require('your/app.js'),
    port = 8080;

//
// Your route would look something like this
//
var example = {
  tracker: {
    message: {
      get: {
        status: 200,
        body: 'respond with a resource'
      }
    }
  }
};

function testRoutes(suite, route, app, path) {
  path = path || '/';
  Object.keys(route).forEach(function (key) {
    if (~verbs.indexOf(key)) {
      return testRoutes(suite, route[key], app, [path, key].join('/'));
    }

    var test = [key, path].join(' ');
    suite[test] = {
      topic: function () {
        request({
          method: key,
          uri: 'http://localhost' + port + path
        }, this.callback);
      },
      'should respond correctly': function (err, res, body) {
        assert.isNull(err);
        assert.equal(res.statusCode, route[key].status);
        assert.equal(body, route[key].body);
      }
    }
  });

  return suite;
}

var suite = vows.describe('api');
testRoutes(suite, example, app);
suite.export(module);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to test the function directly without starting express? I wanted to stub the app object and check that, get, post etc get called as appropriate. The problem is I can't access it from the vow.